# Trying to implement a custom Angular 2 button with "pressed" and "normal" state like Android

Tags: android, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a custom buttom using img tag in Angular 2, it will be similar to this Android piece of code

Android drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn" />
</selector>
```

CSS using div's

```
#btn {
    background: url('img/btn.png');
}

#btn:active {
    background: url('img/btn_pressed.png');
}
```

I tried using CSS with :active, but is too slow for me.

Angular 2 (doesn't work)

```
<img [src]="clicked ? 'img/btn.png' : 'img/btn_pressed.png'" (click)="clicked ? false : true">
```

I want to use property binding or two way databinding without external typescript.

How can i set a initial value for "clicked" variable and [src] property without code?

Comment: Try the click event ```(click) = "clicked = !clicked"``` ? or if you want your way it should be ```(click) = "clicked = clicked ? true : false"```

Comment: I want a similar behavior like :active in CSS, if i click the button it change the src "pressed" and when i release it, use the src "normal"